# git svn rebase -i mess up. Can it be fixed?

Tags: git-svn

I have two local git branches that track two remote svn branches.

I had those setup in a way that master was tracking the svn trunk and 'branch' tracked the svn 'branch'.

recently I was doing some local work on the local 'branch' and due to speed I entered

git svn rebase -i HEAD~2

instead of

git rebase -i HEAD~2.

in the command line after doing two local commits

git did something weird then, it fetched and rebased commits from svn trunk into my local 'branch'. When I went back to master, and tried git svn rebase, those commits that got merged into 'branch' were missing from the master tree. This means that not only is merging between the two branches broken but essentially I can't do work on master because it is not synchronized with trunk. Is there a way to remedy this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can undo the rebase using the reflog. Use `git reflog` to find the commit that the branch pointed to before you ran the rebase. Then use `git reset --hard <COMMIT-ID>` to switch the branch back.

Warning:

Be careful to `git stash` any local changes before doing this (otherwise they will be gone). Also, if you have made other commits after the botched rebase, you will have to rescue them manually (probably using `git cherry-pick`).

Comment: That was the first thing to do. However after doing this and git svn rebase, I had the same result exactly, which makes me think that the git-svn state is somehow changed.

Comment: @Psy-Fi: git-svn does not have much state of its own. Its only state is the state of the remote-tracking branches it creates (one per SVN branch, visible with e.g. `git branch -a` unter `remotes/`). Could you edit the output of `git branch -avv` into the question?

Comment: I did the sane thing after all, I stopped using git to merge between svn branches as it is also suggested to avoid doing so in the official documentation. I will still use git but strictly for local commits on the same branch. Unfortunately I had to delete my local git repository for this to work since I was using this for real work and could not afford any mishaps. Not sure if this question can be considered valid anymore.

Comment: @Psy-Fi: Yes, dcommitting merges is problematic with git-svn, since SVN and git represent branches very differently. It should work in principle, but I have never tested it. Anyway, glad you found a solution that worked.